# details of function bwmorph(image, 'skel') and applylut

Tags: matlab, matrix, mathematical-morphology

I want to understand some detaails of function bwmorph(image, 'skel').

When I typed in matlab console:

```
type bwmorph
```

I found such code about function SKEL

```
%
% Function SKEL
%
function [c,lut] = skel(a)

lut = [];
c = a;
for i = 1:8
    c = applylut(c, lutskel(i));
end
```

Can I get value of array 'lutskel'?

Second question:

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`lut` stands for `look-up-table`, and from MATLAB's documentation in the file `bwmorph.m`,

> The second output argument, LUT, is
>   intentionally undocumented. In the 
>   initial release of the Image
>   Processing Toolbox, all the operations
>   supported by bwmorph used a single
>   look-up table, which was returned as 
>   the second output argument.  In
>   subsequent releases, however, bug
>   fixes  and enhancements resulted in
>   some operations no longer using a
>   single  look-up table. As a result,
>   the second output argument no longer
>   served  the purpose envisioned in the
>   original design of the bwmorph syntax.
>   To  reduce compatibility problems, the
>   second output argument was retained 
>   in the code, but it has been removed
>   from the documentation.  For 
>   operations which do not use a single
>   look-up table, the second output 
>   argument is returned as [].

If you try using the second output argument for the `'skel'` option, you get `[]`. So there's more than one LUT being used and AFAIK they're unaccessible from functions (probably implemented at a low-level).